# Proof verification: Commutativity of set union and intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Theorem. Let $M, N, L$ be sets. Then the following assertions hold:

(1) $M \cap N = N \cap M$

(2) $M \cup N = N \cup M$

*Proof is left as an exercise.*

---

My attempt:

(1) $\forall x: x \in M \cap N \implies x \in M \land x \in N \implies x \in N \cap M \implies N \cap M $

(2) $\forall x : x \in M \cup N \implies x \in M \lor x \in N \implies x \in N \cup M \implies N \cup M$

Is this right or am I either being redundant or jumping to conclusions?

---

Liesen, J., Mehrmann, V. 2015. Linear Algebra. Berlin, Germany.: Springer.

Comment: These properties result from the commutativity of the logical operadors $\wedge$ and $\vee$.

Comment: You're right. I think the question is worthless since commutativity of these operations translate to commutativity of logical operations, and the validity of those is not mathematical.

Comment: By the way, we have a tag for [tag:proof-verification], which has apparently been expanded and renamed [tag:solution-verification].

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish, thanks. That's useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing set equality (often) comes down to showing that each is a subset of the other. I’ll show one direction. You can prove the other directions.

1) Let $x\in M\cap N$. Then $x\in M,N$. Then $x\in N\cap M$. Thus, $M\cap N \subset N\cap M$.

2) Let $x\in M\cup N$. Then $x\in M$ or $x\in N$. Then $x\in N\cup M$. Thus, $M\cup N \subset N\cup M$.

Comment: This is exactly what the OP did, you’ve just deleted a step.

Answer (score 1):

I am proving this using natural deduction:

1. x                   (arbitrary constant - a.k.a - let there be)
2. $x\in M \cup N$         (let's assume)
3. $x\in M \vee x \in N$    (Def of union, 2)
4. $ x\in N \vee x\in M$       (communitativity of disjunction, 3)
5. $ x\ N \cup M $             (Def of union, 4)
6. $x\in M \cup N \rightarrow x\in N \cup M$     (Introduction of implication, 2 to 5)
7. $x\in N \cup M$         (let's assume)
8. $x\in N \vee x \in M$    (Def of union, 2)
9. $ x\in M \vee x\in N$       (communitativity of disjunction, 3)
10. $ x\ M \cup N $             (Def of union, 4)
11. $x\in N \cup M \rightarrow x\in M \cup N$     (Introduction of implication, 7 to 10)
12. $x\in M \cup N \leftrightarrow x\in N \cup M $  (Introduction of equivalence, 11,6)
13. $\forall M,N.(x\in M \cup N \leftrightarrow x\in N \cup M)$  (Introduction of universal, 1-12)
    QED

It could be written a lot nicer when there's an option to use tabs, and indents.